# JQuery Sortable strange behavior connectWith div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable, behavior, levels

I'm trying to connect multiple boxes in multiple levels and sort them between the levels using JQuery Sortable. The problem is that my current solution have a strange behavior when I try to drop items inside another level.

Does anybody know a good solution to make more user friendly the interaction between the user and the boxes?

Here goes a example of my problem:
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jqBy8/)
Please try drop items in the yellow box and sort them.

Thanks!

Comment: What you mean by "a strange behavior" is the blinking effect and not being able to choose a position for the box that is being dragged?

Comment: Yes, its  hard drag items inside the yellow box and almost impossible sort them inside. This example only works with Chorme.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an actual answer for your problem but, I might have a logical reason for such a behavior. Since you want to sort level 1 and level2 items in that case all the shapes means level 1 and putting things into yellow ones is level 2, when you try to put boxes into yellow box the limits in both axises are too small to distingue that level difference. That would cause because you use the x and y axis as a reference so when your curser in the middle of x and y axis of an outer element, it confuses. I would suggest you to try the option axis: "y".